# Chain functions so that they run once previous is complete

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to simply chain some async functions together so they operate in order. I am probably making a basic error.

I just want the printFirst to run and then once complete for printSecond to run.
**below is my code that does not work**

```
const printFirst = ()=>{
  console.log('First')
}
const printSecond = ()=>{
  console.log('Second')
}
// Print this first (after 2 sec)
const first = () =>{
  setTimeout(printFirst,2000)
}
// Once the above function is run then run this
const second = () =>{
  setTimeout(printSecond,2000)
}

first()
.then(second())
```

I get the error

```
node timeout.js
file:///Users/bob/Documents/dev/javascript/node/nodeScratch/timeout.js:20
.then(second())
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at file:///Users/bob/Documents/dev/javascript/node/nodeScratch/timeout.js:20:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

I did see a post here [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain) which suggests that I may not have to use "then". HOwever I am not sure if that is actually relavant to my usecase.

Comment: Your `first` function must return a promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic async functions in JS are based around Promises.  You can write a Promise that waits for a network response or other IO.  You can write one that waits for user interaction.  You can also write one that waits for the end of a `setTimeout`.  This is one example of that:

```js
const printFirst = ()=>{
  console.log('First')
}
const printSecond = ()=>{
  console.log('Second')
}
// Print this first (after 2 sec)
const first = () => new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(printFirst()), 2000)
})

// Once the above function is run then run this
const second = () =>{
  setTimeout(printSecond,2000)
}

first()
  .then (second)
```

As well as wrapping your first function in a `new Promise` call, we also need to switch

```js
first () .then (second ())
```

to

```js
first () .then (second)
```

The initial one fires the `second` function immediately and passes the *result* of it to `.then`.  Instead, we want to pass the *function* itself.  For more complex needs, you could do this instead:

```js
first () .then (result => second (result, someOtherArgument))
```

If you want something else to run after `second`, then it also needs to be wrapped in a `Promise`.